# Gradlew test not working

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

The following command does not execute any test:

```
gradlew test :app:testDebug --continue
```

I must mention I need this line to use it in a Continuous Integration server. I have a few test classes (one for UI testing - espresso). **All my tests inherit TestCase class**

However, if I right-click the tests folder and choose run tests all the tests begin starting, but why this command does not work?

The logs:

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                             
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE     
:app:checkDebugManifest                
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
..............................
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:assembleReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE      
:app:testReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE      
:app:test UP-TO-DATE
```

Comment: What sort of error are you seeing? Try this: ./gradlew test :app:testDebug --continue

Comment: @davehenry - I posted the logs (no error, simply the tests won't run).

Comment: @AlexandruCircus Did you managed to fix this? I struggling with this issue as well. My Android test `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` works fine, but the test in `src/test/java` doesn't run at all.

Comment: @wint Simply moved unit test classes from src/test/java into android default test folder, and used this command: "./gradlew test --continue". But this command will fail if no emulator or device was found, so in my bitrise workflow I added another step of starting an android emulator BEFORE performing the testing step.

Comment: Have you tried to perform `./gradlew test`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `./gradlew testDebug --stacktrace` to only run debug tests